# High side driver schematic

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, current, pic, driver

I'm working on an android controlled input/output/gauges manager for cars based on a pic24 micro controller. I'm really not an electronics expert so I had someone working on the schematics but he has no time anymore.

I previously asked a question here about the outputs schematic that he designed: [Mosfet as switch for high output current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312790/mosfet-as-switch-for-high-output-current) and it turns out the schematic was crap!

I've found automotive high side drivers for a fair price and I think these would do the job perfectly. I want 5 outputs to drive various loads (leds, solenoids, dc motors, etc) and turn them on/off from the pic micro controller.

So I've chosen a single channel driver (for bigger loads) and a 4 channels driver (supports 12A so I would think that equates to 3A per channel?).
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/cd/1f/d3/43/b8/2d/48/0b/DM00157127.pdf/files/DM00157127.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00157127.pdf

Here is the schematic that I think would be ok for both drivers. Is 1w rating enough for the zener diode and is 1a enough for the ground diode? I think I can share them between the 2 drivers, is that correct?

[image]

Comment: You cannot just stick 12A through these devices and not do any calculations about power consumption. Think about one channel passing 3A through a typical on resistance of 140mR. 3*3*0.14 = 1.26W. You have four channels running, that's 5.04W. Then look at the thermal resistance when you have a big copper heatsink and you've really layed out the board well of 26.8 degrees C. That's a temp raise of 135 degrees! If you really do want 12A you cannot use that four channel part.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out thermal resistance. I hadn't even though of that... But doing the calculations with P = A x V, that means that without a heatsink, the quad channel driver supports only 0.09A per channel!! Is that right?? 4.47W = 0.37A x 12V. 4.47W x 26.8C per W = about 120 C + 30 (Ambient) = 150 C (Min shutdown temp). 0.37/4= 0.09A!!! Is my calculation wrong? That seems ridiculously low...

Comment: I * I * R is the calculation you should be using. Each channel is 120R. So add up all the channels' power consumption. I think it should be a lot higher than 90mA, but it will be loads less than 12A. Those datasheets' headline figures are so misleading when you can't in practice put a heatsink on devices like that.

Comment: 120mR, sorry, not 120R!

Comment: With that equation, I get 2.83A per channel (very acceptable)! 4.47w max / 4 = 1.12W per channel. 2.83 x 2.83 * 0.14 = 1.12W. This is a HUGE difference compared to using P = A x V... Can you explain when to use one equation or the other? It makes no sense to me that equations give such different results. I don't get why one is dependent on voltage and the other one not at all? Like I said, my electronics knowledge is limited so maybe I'm missing something??

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/my-linear-voltage-regulator-is-overheating-very-fast

Ok from that very informative thread, it seems that with P = A x V, V is not the total voltage but the voltage drop across the device... The datasheet says 20mv at 0.07A but I don't know how that relates at higher current...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, weekend... Sounds like you largely worked it out though. The external load is dropping the voltage which just leaves what is dropped across the internal FET. If the FET is hard on, then R is small and you're using the rearranged version of power. P = V * I, but V = I * R, so P = I * I * R. As you know R when it is turned on and you [presumably] know how much current each channel will take, you can work out all you need. Compare  this with a linear regulator where you might have 5V in and 3V3 out, in that case you *are* dropping 1.7V and your power dissipation is 1.7 * I.

Comment: BTW, I am not sure about your original question, but were it me, I'd use separate diodes for the two chips.